# What's the benefit of using jQuery offset over getBoundingClientRect

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

Through testing, I am seeing a slight performance issue with using the following (especially on older browsers) - with many operations a second:

```
elX = $(el).offset().left;
elY = $(el).offset().top;
elWidth = $(el).outerWidth();
```

I have come across using a Vanilla JS version instead:

```
elX = el.getBoundingClientRect.left;
elY = el.getBoundingClientRect.top;
elWidth = el.offsetWidth;
```

Do they function exactly the same? Is it safe to switch over to the Vanilla JS version and have the results be the same each time?

If so, why wouldn't jQuery use them from the start - what have they added to make it different and much worse at performance

Comment: jQuery is open source, so, you can  [check that for yourself](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/025da4dd343e6734f3d3c1b4785b1548498115d8/src/offset.js). Generally, though, to the question, "What's the benefit of using jQuery", the answer's most likely: *nothing*.

Comment: Keep in mind that jQuery was written in an age where we needed a number of polyfills and many of its capabilities did not have native equivalents. These days, jQuery has been mostly obviated by the continuous evolution of Javascript specifications.

Comment: First you are using the library wrong: a jquery wrapper is not a small object it should be created sporadically. And even methods like `offset()` was doing a lot in previous versions to handle edge cases of IE<8, having to look at computed styles etc. So you could start by improving your code  `const $el = $(el); const offset = $el.offset; elX = offset.left;
offset.top;
elWidth = $el.outerWidth();`